# inequality $10<2^{2^{\frac {3}{\log_2 \log_2 10}}}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

While working on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083217/prove-that-22-sqrt310) I ended up with $10<2^2{^{\frac {3}{\log_2 \log_2 10}}}$
I am looking for answers using methods similar [to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/415537/3936) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423359/3936) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227910/3936) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140347/3936).
Alternative original inequality was $3>(\log_2 \log_2 10)^2$
$$3>(\log_2 \log_2 10)^2$$
$$\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}>(\log_2 \log_2 10)$$
$$2^\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}>2^{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}$$
$$2^\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}>{ \log_2 10}$$
$$2^{2^\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}}>2^{ \log_2 10}$$
$$2^{2^\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}}> 10$$

Comment: @Henry : I Included my workings but I cant see the fault

Comment: I had not spotted that you had killed a squared exponent in your statement. Still worth noting how close this is: $(\log_2\log_2 10)^2 \approx 2.999896$   and $2^{2^\frac{3}{(\log_2 \log_2 10)}}\approx 10.00096$

Comment: Accordin to this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2%28log_2%2810%29%29-sqrt%283%29, the difference between the two of them is very small as Henry noted, so the powers involved should be very big. You can prove for example that $log_2(log_2(10))<log_2(7/3)$ which is not nearly good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I made a (stupid) mistake in my previous answer and this one is now in a different spirit.

$$3>(\log_2 \log_2 10)^2 \iff$$

$$\sqrt{3}>\log_2 \log_2 10 \iff$$

$$2^{2^\sqrt{3}}> 10$$

Now, $\sqrt{3}>\frac{989}{571}$.

Also, $$2^{\frac{989}{571}}>\frac{877}{264}$$

Hence $$2^{2^{\sqrt{3}}} > 2^{2^{\frac{989}{571}}} > 2^{\frac{877}{264}} >10$$

This was all done by computer of course, but I have done it so that it is all verifiable by hand (at least to the extent of only needing powers of natural numbers and patience).

Comment: I think this is not the kind of answer that the OP is looking for. Notice that if you use a computer for justifying your choice of fractions, why does not take directly a fraction $a/b$ such that $3 > a/b > (\log_2 \log_2 10)^2$?

Comment: @AlexSilva the point is that you can verify each of the inequalities I write (at least in theory) by hand using only simple calculations. This is something you cannot do to prove (say) $\log_2 10 <\frac{a}{b}$. So while I may have used a computer to write the answer, with enough patience and care (!!) even a secondary school student could verify it. Moreover, I just don't think there's a better way other than outright calculating it (on a computer/calculator).